# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths causing app to be unresponsive

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I have a table view which is populated from a fetched results controller. I'm also using NSTimer to make an API call every minute which pulls in any new data to be displayed. This happens asynchronously using GCD with a new managed object context, and uses mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification to merge the changes in to the main managed object context on completion. This triggers the fetched results controller delegate methods and any new rows are inserted into the table with insertRowsAtIndexPaths.

This is all working as expected, however I'm seeing a 5 second pause between UITableView endUpdates being called and the new cell appearing in the table view. During this pause the app doesn't respond to any touch events (tab bar, scrolling the table view etc).

I'm a bit confused about where to start debugging this issue - the cell configuration all happens before before the endUpdates call, and doesn't seem to be taking a long time.

The code is reasonably complicated, but I can post it up if required.

**EDIT**:

Here is a log extract showing the times of each call from the context merge to endUpdates being called:

```
2011-05-22 15:29:47.119 myapp[4136:7c1b] got background save notification
2011-05-22 15:29:47.124 myapp[4136:7c1b] controllerWillChangeContent
2011-05-22 15:29:47.128 myapp[4136:7c1b] NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert
2011-05-22 15:29:47.132 myapp[4136:7c1b] controllerDidChangeContent
2011-05-22 15:29:47.138 myapp[4136:7c1b] numberOfSectionsInTableView called
2011-05-22 15:29:47.140 myapp[4136:7c1b] numberOfSectionsInTableView called
2011-05-22 15:29:47.144 myapp[4136:7c1b] numberOfRowsInSection called
2011-05-22 15:29:47.157 myapp[4136:7c1b] cellForRowAtIndexPath called
2011-05-22 15:29:47.195 myapp[4136:7c1b] cellForRowAtIndexPath returning configured cell
2011-05-22 15:29:47.212 myapp[4136:7c1b] endUpdates called
```

Answer (score 6):

You've probably solved the problem yourself by now but I came across this question when I had literally the **exact** same problem today and think it needs answering for posterity.

What is most likely happening is that you have set up your `NSManagedObjectContext` on the main thread and are then doing your `save` on a different thread, causing the animations on the `UITableView` (which is on the main thread) to wait until that GCD thread has been taken care of.

Simple fix: do all your computationally intensive stuff as well as the inserting into the MOC within your GCD thread, but then do the `save` on the main thread, like so:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{       
  // Do all your processing and inserting here

  // ... and then, when you're done:
  dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSError *anyError = nil;
      BOOL success = [self.managedObjectContext save:&anyError];
      if(!success) {
          // Error handling
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this definitely needed answering for posterity, because I also came across this exact behavior and would have probably spent hours (on top of what I already have) pouring through documentation and randomly trying things until it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check how much time it takes for tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to complete?
Or maybe your "layoutSubviews" in your custom tableview cell takes a lot of time?

Comment: Yeah, I added logging at each step and everything happens very quickly. I'll update the original question with a log extract.

Comment: Try running your app through instruments with a time profiler and check the spike which will show up.

Comment: Instruments didn't show any spikes during the hanging. I am using custom cells, though not with a subclass of UITableViewCell - they are set up when the dequeued cell is nil. When a new cell is inserted, there are no memory allocations performed - just an update of labels and an imageview which was set up when the cell was created. I can post the code if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @barrym What are your cells subclass of? When changes are merged, is insertRowsAtIndexPaths called automatically or you call it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I think I've narrowed it down to the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification, insertRowsAtIndexPaths looks to have been a red herring. I'm still not entirely clear what the actual issue is, but still plugging away at it.